# How to wire a referenced object of a Spring bean

Tags: java, spring

Here is my example bean:

```
@Component
public class FirstBean {
    private List<String> foo;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Now I want to wire the `foo` list from the `FirstBean` into the `SecondBean` bean. Something like this or maybe in the XML config file:

```
@Component
public class SecondBean {
    @Autowired
    private List<String> foo
}
```

How can I wire a referenced object of a bean and not the bean itself?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to wire firstbean.foo?

Comment: Yes, the referenced object on the ```foo``` variable of the ```FirstBean``` bean.

Answer (score 0):

You could proceed as follow:

```
@Component
public class TheList {

    private List<String> theList;

}

@Component
public class FirstBean {

    @Autowired
    private TheList foo;

}

@Component
public class SecondBean {

    @Autowired
    private TheList foo;

}
```

Comment: is it a good practice to unnecessory wrapper around List<String> foo?

Comment: Yes, but when I have no control over the beans I can't do that. For example I want to directly wire a internal object of the ```HttpServletRequest```class like this: ```request.getSession().getAttribute("mysession");```

Comment: @RobertMoszczynski Then you could probably use the @Scope(value="session") annotation on a bean instead.

Comment: Ok, this is actually cool for sessions. But what if I want to directly wire an internal object from a different bean in general?